# Exception when DisplayRootViewFor calls GetAllInstances override in Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2 with the default MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) IoC container configuration.

I am requesting a collection of ViewModels that implement a certain interface by using IoC.GetAll<ISupportFeatureX> (Yes, I'm eventually removing the [ServiceLocator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) anti-pattern).

All aforementioned ViewModels are decorated with the [Export(typeof(ISupportFeatureX))] attribute.

Everything works as expected until the default view is loaded in OnStartup(). For some reason, GetAllInstances() is called instead of GetInstance() and I get an exception.

```
"Could not locate any instances of contract <Namespace>.Views.ShellView."
```

My CaliburnBootstrapper is as follows:

```
public class CaliburnBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    CompositionContainer container;

    public CaliburnBootstrapper() { this.Initialize(); }


    void ConfigureIocContainer()
    {
        try
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x))
                                                             .OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());
            this.container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            var batch = new CompositionBatch();

            var eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
            var windowManager = new WindowManager();

            batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(windowManager);
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(eventAggregator);

            batch.AddExportedValue(this.container);
            batch.AddExportedValue(catalog);

            this.container.Compose(batch);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.logger.Error(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}


    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        this.container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        var contract = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
        var exports = this.container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Any()) return exports;

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }


    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        var contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
        var exports = this.container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Any()) return exports.First();

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DisplayRootViewFor<IShellViewModel>();
    }
```

My Views and ViewModels are in separate projects, hence the SelectAssemblies override.

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        assemblies.Add(typeof (IShellViewModel).Assembly);
        assemblies.Add(typeof (ShellView).Assembly);
        return assemblies;
    }
```

The app worked fine with this Caliburn.Micro setup until I override GetAllInstances(). Looking at the Caliburn.Micro source code, I can't see any calls to GetAllInstances() in the DisplayRootViewFor() call chain.

Any explanation as to why GetInstance() resolves ShellView but the same code in GetAllInstances() does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of Caliburn.Micro (CM) is to instantiate our views for you. Once you override "GetAllInstances", CM no longer creates the view instances for you, but instead, looks for objects from the container.

Since the Views are not registered with the container (in this case, using MEF [Export] attribute), the GetAllInstances call throws an exception when the requested View is not found in the container.

This was a simple issue of not understanding the internals of Caliburn.Micro and MEF as the IoC container.